# Why returns float.Parse() without decimal places wrong result?

Tags: c#, .net

```
float.Parse("534818068")
```

returns: 534818080

I understand that there are many complications with float and decimal values. But maybe someone could explain this behaviour to me.

Thanks!

Comment: `float` tends to single-precision, it only supports less than 10-digit floating-point notation. What I get is `5.348181E+08` which actually rounds up to 7 digits.

Comment: "I understand that there are many complications with float and decimal values" - what are the complications that you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers have a relative precision, i.e. something like 7 or 8 digits. So only the first 7 or 8 digits are correct, independent of the actual total size of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are stored internally using the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) standard (a sign, a biased exponent and a fraction).

`float` numbers are stored with a 32 bits representation, which means they will have a precision of 7 digits.
On the other hand, `double` are stored with a 64 bits representation, thus having 15-16 digits ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double)).

Which is why you shouldn't usually compare floats for equality for instance.

Comment: That doesn't (in itself) explain what the OP's seeing though. (It would be fine for `double`, for example.)

Comment: True. Because double has a larger precision (stored with 64 bits vs 32 bits for float). However, I think the explanation of what the OP is seeing lies in how the numbers are represented internally, thus my answer.

Comment: Not really - because without mentioning precision, it doesn't answer it at all. Integers can always be represented precisely in a binary floating point type with a large enough mantissa to handle that integer. Basically, you're only providing half the relevant information at the moment. It's a fine start, but it doesn't answer the question *yet*.